# \hat not working in LaTex equation

Tags: equations, symbols

I need to have a hat sign on top of X in the shown image
[image]

The code for generating the above is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12 pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=2cm,top=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm}
\usepackage{upgreek}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0em}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\usepackage[super,comma]{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{longtable}

\linespread{1.0} 
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\usepackage{forloop}
\newcounter{loopcntr}
\newcommand{\rpt}[2][1]{%
  \forloop{loopcntr}{0}{\value{loopcntr}<#1}{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\on}[1][1]{
  \forloop{loopcntr}{0}{\value{loopcntr}<#1}{&\cellcolor{gray}}
}
\newcommand{\off}[1][1]{
  \forloop{loopcntr}{0}{\value{loopcntr}<#1}{&}
}

\definecolor{orange}{HTML}{FF7F00}

\newcommand{\appendixnumberline}[1]{Appendix\space}

\let\oldappendix\appendix
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\appendix}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\let\protect\numberline\protect\appendixnumberline}%
  \renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{Appendix~\csname the##1\endcsname\quad}%
  \oldappendix
}
\makeatother
\date{}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}
{4}{0pt}%
% display heading, like subsubsection
                                    {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                    {0.00005ex}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
 \makeatother

\begin{document}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt} \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt} \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\begin{align}
\label{eq:Xtrd}
    \text{\pmb{X}}_{\text{\pmb{trd}}} &= \text{\pmb{W}}\pmb{\hat{\upbeta}_\text{trd}} \\
\label{eq:Xadd}
    \text{\pmb{X}}_{\text{\pmb{add}}} &= \text{\pmb{W}}\pmb{\hat{\upbeta}_\text{add}} \\
\label{eq:Xgxe}
    \text{\pmb{X}}_{\text{\pmb{gxe}}} &= \text{\pmb{W}}\pmb{\hat{\upbeta}_\text{gxe}} 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

When I use `\hat{}` it gives compilation error. That is working for beta, but not X.

Comment: Can you complete your code so that it can directly be compiled? For example, what is `\pmb`? And why do you need this command? Else, something like `\mathbf{\hat{X}}` would probably work.

Comment: ```\pmb``` is used to bold the greek letters. I used it instead of ```\textbf```` to make the font consistent.

Comment: ```\mathbf{\hat{X}}``` did not work either. Let me update the code with all the packages.

Comment: To understand our request please copy your posted code code into a new blank file and compile. Next, EDIT your question accordingly. Thanks

Comment: I have edited the code as requested.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\pmb` (poor man bold) gives ugly result (text write 2 times to obtain "bold"). Uses instead `\mathbf` and `\textbf` for bold. And `\boldsymbol` for bold greek (`boldsymbol` is from package `amsbsy` loaded by package `mathtools`).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \text{\pmb{X}}_{\text{\pmb{trd}}} = \text{\pmb{W}}\pmb{\hat{\upbeta}_\text{trd}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \mathbf{\hat{X}}_{\text{\textbf{trd}}}=\mathbf{W\hat{\upbeta}}_{\textbf{\text{trd}}}
\end{equation}

%Using \boldsymbol for bold greek character:
\begin{equation}
    \mathbf{\hat{X}}_{\text{\textbf{trd}}}=\mathbf{W\hat{\boldsymbol{\upbeta}}}_{\textbf{\text{trd}}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Edit

As David Carlisle explains in the comment, it's better to load the **bm** package (replace `\usepackage{mathtools}` by `\usepackage{bm,mathtools}`), and you don't even need to replace `\boldsymbol` by `\bm` because when the **bm** package is loaded, the **mathtools** package redefine `\boldsymbol` as an alias for `\bm`.

But for new documents, `\bm` is probably faster to type than `\boldsymbol`.

Comment: This is pefect and very well explained. Many thanks.

Comment: better to use `\bm` in most cases

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Can you elaborate where and why? So I can learn a new thing.

Comment: `\bm` is from the bm package (part of the core latex tools ) it produces better spacing than \boldsymbol and avoids setting everything 4 times as \boldsymbol does, ams redefine \boldsymbol as an alias for \bm if both loaded (I wrote bm:-)